# Powershell: Trying to return specific values from a WMIObject query

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that will pull details about specific software on my computer. To accomplish this, I am trying to use Get-WMIObject. I am able to pull the list of all software on my computer using. Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product. I would like to manipulate this to return only specific software. I created a variable with the list of software and added it to the script. Now I am getting an error that name "is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program". I same name instead of what is in my code because I have tried many variations (name, $_.Name, WmiObject.Name, .Name). All return a similar error. I checked Get-Member to verify, and name is a property of the objects I should be returning. I have also tried parentheses starting with where-object and also wrapping the entire script in parentheses.

```
$SoftWare = @(
    'Office 16 Click-to-Run Licensing Component',
    'Adobe Acrobat',
    'Google Chrome',
    'Local Administrator Password Solution',
)


Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$._name -EQ $SoftWare}
```

Comment: wouldnt recommend you to query win32_product. much better to query the reg, this function can help you with that https://gist.github.com/SeeminglyScience/d7be8c59875bd389df820c8356f137f9#file-get-installedsoftware-ps1

Comment: Win32_product is broken and can actually cause problems in specific scenario's (because it forces a re-register of all msi components on your system). I always recommend to avoid this class and use the registry method noted by @SantiagoSquarzon instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  You are using the wrong comparison operator.  YOu would use "-eq" when comparing one value to another single value.  You are comparing one value to an array of values, so try this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.name -in $SoftWare}
```

-In will determine if the a single value is contained within an array of values.  Oh, "Where-object" query was incorrect to.  Move the period over one.